# How to cut part of string from a sentence in linux?

Tags: shell

How can I get release version detail using `cut` or `awk` or `grep`?

```
|1NP|192.168.4.10|disprofiling-blue|dts|136190715|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/disprofiling:perf-latest-release-20-05-13-REL
|1NP|192.168.4.10|disprofiling-green|dts|136191553|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/disprofiling:perf-latest-release-20-04-29-REL
|1NP|192.168.4.10|profileing-blue|bdllts|144765480|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/profileing:perf-latest-release-20-05-12-REL
|1NP|192.168.4.10|profileing-green|bdllts|138530558|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/profileing:perf-latest-release-20-05-12-REL
|1NP|192.168.4.10|recorsrv-blue|bdllts|139683172|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/recorsrv:perf-latest-release-20-05-12-REL
```

Example:

```
|1NP|192.168.4.10|recorsrv-blue|bdllts|139683172|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/recorsrv:perf-latest-release-20-05-12-REL
```

Expected output:

```
-20-05-12-REL
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about release info; eg, append the posting with a section for expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the output you are asking for comes from a file (let's say `file.txt`), and assuming that such file may look like this:

```
|1NP|192.168.4.10|disprofiling-blue|dts|136190715|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/disprofiling:perf-latest-release-20-05-13-REL
|1NP|192.168.4.10|disprofiling-green|dts|136191553|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/disprofiling:perf-latest-release-20-04-29-REL
|1NP|192.168.4.10|profileing-blue|bdllts|144765480|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/profileing:perf-latest-release-20-05-12-REL
|1NP|192.168.4.10|profileing-green|bdllts|138530558|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/profileing:perf-latest-release-20-05-12-REL
|1NP|192.168.4.10|recorsrv-blue|bdllts|139683172|awsxxxxxxx:5100/bdltts/recorsrv:perf-latest-release-20-05-12-REL
```

And also assuming that the desired output you want to get is as follows:

```
20-05-12-REL
```

You can try this:

```
cat file.txt |cut -d\: -f3 |cut -d\- -f4-7
```

Answer (score 0):

See this `-f4-7` part? MAN this was priceless and works like magic

I show you my code:

```
~/Desktop$ cat s.txt 

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-05 04:16 CEST
Nmap scan report for ip-184-168-227-141.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.131.241)
Host is up (0.23s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
21/tcp  open  ftp
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 47.34 seconds

cool@cool-V100-X:~/Desktop$ cat s.txt | grep "184-168-227-141 " | cut -d " " -f 5 | tr '-' '.' | cut -d "." -f 2-5 | cat>sCopied.txt
cool@cool-V100-X:~/Desktop$ cat sCopied.txt
184.168.227.141
```

I took out the Ip just with your last `-f4-6` magic part

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Thanks for sharing another use case.